# How can windows kernel driver catch int3 breakpoints and handle it?

Tags: windows, exception, kernel, driver, windbg

How can a windows kernel driver register an int3 exception handler?

For example, another module named A raise an int3 exception, how can our kernel driver B catch the exception and handle it, just like the windbg do?

Comment: Presumably, WinDbg calls [WaitForDebugEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-waitfordebugevent).

Comment: As far as i know Windbg does not have a kernel driver it does everything from usermode. You can use try except in a limited scenerios in kmode

Comment: Can you be more specific and tell us what problems you're trying to solve? Are you talking about breakpoints triggered by a process (in user-mode), or by a driver (in kernel-mode)? For the second case you can't do anything from another driver. If a kernel debugger is attached it will handle that breakpoint, if not a bug check will be generated.

Comment: @icebp: I understand the request that OP wants to implement a kernel driver to act like a kernel debugger and catch other kernel drivers int3

Comment: That's simply not possible. At least not in documented ways. And hooking the kernel INT3 exception handler is not possible on 64-bit Windows versions due to patch guard.